# C - timeout on a function that reaturn string

Tags: c, select, timeout

I have a C code that send a request to a card, then store a response from the card and print it.
To store the return command I use :

```
char * returnCommand = Cmd_Debug_GetResponse();
```

No problem there.
My problem is when I want to set a timeout on this response. If the function "Cmd_Debug_GetResponse()" does not return anything in 5 seconds, I want the program to keep going to the next lines.

I try to use **select()** in this way, but with no good results :
(I wrote only the interesting part)

```
fd_set input_set;
struct timeval timeout;
int ready_for_reading = 0;
FD_ZERO(&input_set);
FD_SET(0, &input_set);

timeout.tv_sec = 5;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
ready_for_reading = select(1, &input_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
if(ready_for_reading)
{
    char * returnCommand = Cmd_Debug_GetResponse();
    printf("OK : %s\n", returnCommand);
} else {
    printf("5 secs are over\n");
}
```

The code always loop on the timeout...
Can someone tell me what is wrong, and what to do ?

Thanks

Comment: select works with file descriptors. Where and how your I/O is opened? Are you sure that the I/O FD is 0?

Comment: clearly select is not the right solution, according to Viet answer. I'm now looking for other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`select()` function allow a program to monitor multiple file descriptor, waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready" for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible). In your code, there is no file descriptor was opened. You use wrong function and purpose

To resolve your problem, you can use timer. Please see that link:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html

Comment: OK, I see what was my mistake.
But do you have any simple code of how to use timer_create ? The example given is not very clear for me..

Comment: You can try to create a simple code to test. And if you get the problem, you can ask me. I think the example in that link is simple